# C# Win7 регулировка звука микрофона

Tags: c#, аудио

Проблема встала при регулировки громкости воспроизведения, пишу что то типо караоке плеера, микрофон должен включаться с начала воспроизведения и выключаться в конце. Как регулировать громкость записи разобрался через библиотеку Naudio, но это не подходит, так как, идет задержка в звуке если что то говорить в микрофон. А вот если использовать ползунок громкость воспроизведения то всё гуд, только Naudio не имеет к нему доступ.

[image: Нужно регулировать Громкость воспроизведения]

Comment: winapi посмотри : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440588/how-can-i-programmatically-control-the-microphone-and-microphone-boost-settings

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, что то не могу найти... может есть варианты с naudio?

Comment: Больше нет вариантов как это можно реализовать?

Comment: может это поможет: https://www.codeproject.com/kb/audio-video/mixersetcontroldetails.aspx